# how to separating a nested list python

Tags: python-2.7, list

I am trying to create a new list build from the items inside the list
for example `list = [[math,chemistery],biology]`

I would like to create the new list

```
new_list = [math, chemistery, biology]
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works when items that are nested are really list or subclass of list, and there are no further nesting.

```
new_list = []
for item in old_list:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        new_list.extend(item)        # expand nested items
    else:
        new_list.append(item)        # simply append one
```

If you have other list-like types you may switch to
`isinstance(item, (list, other_list_like_class))`

Tips: Better not shadow class name 'list' by assigning values to it.

If further nesting exists, simply add an recursion as in

```
def expand_nested_list(old_list):
    new_list = []
    for item in old_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            new_list.extend(expand_nested_list(item))
        else:
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list
```

This will lead to
`expand_nested_list([[[1], 2], 3])      # returns [1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [['math', 'chemistery'], 'biology']
list(np.hstack(my_list)) # returns ['math', 'chemistery', 'biology']
```